# How to draw a picture with mathematical equations

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, equation

Recently I have seen some pictures that could be drawn by some mathematical equations like the [Batman Logo](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BatmanCurve.html) and the [Heart](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html).

Is there a specific way to find the equations which draw a desired picture? (e.g. I want to draw the letter S with some mathematical equations).

Thanks.

p.s. I guess it is an optimization problem. First get some samples from the border of the desired picture and then finding a function which has the minimum difference from those samples.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/637/134) will be useful.

Comment: Have you looked at Bezier curves (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BezierCurve.html) and Creating graphics with spline primitives (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateGraphicsWithSplinePrimitives.html)?

Comment: @b.gatessucks thank you for your link. it was useful. but I need the equations. Is there any way to find the equations after finding the points of the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your picture is in black and white you may want to have a look at this
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/nlinfit.html

You can get the points and perform regression on them. Linear regression will get you a line. Nonlinear will get you something more accurate.

If the picture is more complex, then you will have to extract some features and it gets more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. let me check it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The more samples you have from the layout of you picture the closer to its function you can get by using numerical analysis for approximation (e.g., you can find a polynomial containing all your samples).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how? is there any implemented code? or how I can implement one? I need more details.
Thank you very much

Comment: I suppose there should be a numerical analysis library in mathematica. Numerical approximations are surely there.

Comment: And does it provides an equation? or just draws a polynomial which contains all the samples?

Comment: It's impossible to provide an equation based on a finite set of samples: there is an infinite number of equations that will correspond. Choosing one of them is what approximation methods are about.

Comment: Just one is enough. Is there any Matlab code which give us the equation?